# Content-Type and Representations

Tags: django, url, url-routing, content-type

What is the common convention for supporting multiple representation (e.g. html, json, xml) for resources (e.g. blog, user) in django?

First, I don't know how I should format my urls.  For example, what your take on using either of these urls to request xml format

- `/<resource>.<format>`, e.g. `/blogs/123.xml`
- `/<format>/<resource>`, e.g. `/xml/blogs/123`
- `/<resource>?format=<format>`, e.g. `/blogs/123?format=xml`

Should I just rely on the `Content-Type` passed parameter?  What about having multiple mobile representation (e.g. iphone, mobile, palm) and full browser representation?

What about views?  What's the convention for choosing the right templates without having a lot of if statements or much duplicate code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What I might do, if this were to work out, is:

- Your views look for the `Accept` header (I think that's what you were talking about) and decide which content-type to send back based on the `Accept` header.
- You have a middleware which looks for an extension in the Request-URI, removes it, and adds the associated content-type to the request `Accept` header.

For this solution, content-types in the URL would always be represented as an associated file extension, neither part of the query-string nor part of the resource name. But aside from browser-generated requests, the content-types *should* be coming in through the `Accept` header.

So the request comes in as:

```
GET /blogs/123.xml HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
```

The middleware transforms that to:

```
GET /blogs/123 HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Accept: application/xml
```

Your view sees `application/xml` and returns a response with XML content.

Comment: Neat (and +1) - but could you provide some sample view code? Doesn't this risk littering your view code with lots of switches depending on the content-type? I can't immediately think of an elegant way around it, but I'd be interested to see if anyone else can.